# Center Align Text with Select Option

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

How to vertically Align a text with a Select Option.

[image]

Link: http://mink7.com/projects/test/dashboard.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use labels as in [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7mxq/2/). Markup:

```
<form action="">
    <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
    <select id="startDate">
        <option value="Mar 04">Mar 04</option>
    </select>
    <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
    <select id="endDate">
        <option value="Aug 04">Aug 04</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When this does not work, then there are some inherited styles interfering and try to set `vertical-align: middle` as shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E7mxq/3/).

Answer (score 1):

In IE and Chrome the select tag text is aligned center automatically, not in firefox. To only target firefox with a padding, without compromising IE and Chrome: 
Use a browser specific hack for FF and give it a padding-top:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .select select{
                 padding-top: 8px;
                 }
        }
```