# Padding-Left in Select Tag (dropdown) in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As far as I can tell, there's no solution for getting consistent padding-left within select boxes (dropdowns) across all modern browsers.

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option>Planes</option>
    <option>Trains</option>
    <option>Automobiles</option>
</select>
```

The solution I've heard is to use text-indent, but that breaks entirely in Firefox, let alone is supported sporadically across other browsers. If you use a combination, you actually get completely different results across all major browsers.

```
.dropdown {
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

**IE:** only **padding** renders

**Chrome: both** render

**Safari:** only **text-indent** renders

**Firefox: padding**, with weird text-indent **bug**

Is there another way to resolve this issue? It seems like the best approach is to ditch text-indent and try and figure out a way to indent in Safari without it, since everything else can handle the padding just fine.

Relevant Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Lrh/1/

Comment: Here 

[Center Align Text with Select Option][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028788/center-align-text-with-select-option

Comment: You can see here 

[Center Align Text with Select Option][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028788/center-align-text-with-select-option

Comment: How to vertically Align a text with a Select Option.

[Center Align Text with Select Option][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028788/center-align-text-with-select-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me, there is no good way to do this. Styling select boxes has always been buggy, with limited support.

Since you can use jQuery, I would suggest something like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), which both can style your select box by including a "fake" select box, while hiding the real one.

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Thank you, think!

Comment: @M.Herold No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best thing that I have found to work:

```
select{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

At the time of writing, this works on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I made this work without using a select plugin is to add empty spaces before the text like this:

```
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text Here</option>
```

This will have similar effect to padding-left

Answer (score -4):

You'll have to approach this in a different way. This is what you should do:

```
option
{
position: relative;
padding-left: 5px; /*or whatever*/
}
```

This is a universal approach, and it gets the job done.

Comment: Could you demonstrate this in a fiddle? Styling the option tag in Chrome does nothing. I haven't checked against other browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/9da9q/ I assume you meant to do "left", not "padding-left", but both don't work so it's neither here nor there.